# Linting JSON template is failing. coming with error bash failed message

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I am trying to linting arm.json showing in the below screenshot.
[image]

FOr that I configured the below 2 tasks in the pipeline
[image]

and coming up with following error and logs. Please suggest
[image]

Updated screenshot1:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description and screenshots, there is no "template.json" in your Repo.

The script "jsonlint template.json" in your cmd task is not corresponding to the file in your Repo. You could try editing your script as "jsonlint arm.json" to see if it works.

Comment: HI RoyWang, Thank you for the response. I tried that step but still same error occurred.  However After changing file name it is supposted change name right? But why it is not happening. Please suggest further. Please find updated screenshot in my first thread.

Comment: Please check whether the selected edited "DSC" branch is corresponding to the branch in your pipeline.
If so and the error still occurs, please share the screenshots when re-running pipeline and reproducing this issue in UI.